# How are so many webcams on servers which have URL ~ \view\index.shtml?

Tags: internet, webcam, url

[image]

How does this happen? Why do all these webcams have similar HTTP access URLs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the default public page for network cameras from [Axis](http://www.axis.com/).

Answer (score 0):

They use the same or similar IP Camera providers?
Maybe that's just the 'standard' that IP cameras use as the URL for accessing the live feed.

Similar to routers - how is it the case that you still see many unsecured wireless networks?
(I know the majority of ISP's now implement *at least* WEP as standard on their devices)
Simply because that's how the users receive the devices and don't bother to change it; either because they're not bothered or aren't aware of the risks.